# Filtering content (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, categories

HTML:

```
<div class="filter">
    <a href="#category-1">category 1</a>
    <a href="#category-2">category 2</a>
</div>
<ul class="items">
    <li class="category-1">item 1</li>
    <li class="category-1">item 2</li>
    <li class="category-2">item 3</li>
    <li class="category-2">item 4</li>
</ul>
```

What I want is for example clicking on 'category 1' link should hide all other category items from the list.

I understand jQuery's .filter() selector can be used but I'm not sure how to implement it for my purpose here.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('div.filter').delegate('a', 'click', function (event) {
  $('ul.items li').hide().filter('.' + this.href.slice(this.href.indexOf("#") + 1)).show();

  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! BTW, why delegate instead of the simpler .click(function(), just curious? :)

Comment: I find it cleaner than adding the event to each anchor tag.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you'll be doing something like this: `$('.items li').hide(); $('.category-1').show();`

The first to hide all other menu items, the latter to show the selected ones :)
You can simply put it in the `onclick` of the `<a>` tag.