# filter content by tags with raw text

Tags: jquery, filter, tags, html-lists

I'm trying to create a filter / tagging system. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703961/filtering-content-jquery) works well but uses classes and not raw text. Most of the jquery sorting / filtering seems to use classes and I would like to use raw text.

My html is set up like this.

```
<div class="pin">
<img src="/thumbnail.jpg" >
<span>10.08.12</span>
<ul>
<li>Red</li>
<li>Green</li>
<li>Blue</li>
<li>Yellow</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

The tags are within `.li` elements but I would like them to become links that would filter the page of content.

```
<div class="pin">
<img src="/thumbnail.jpg" >
<span>10.08.12</span>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Red</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Green</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Blue</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Yellow</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Whats the best way to only show the `.pin` based on if they have that particular list item. For example clicking `<li><a href="#">Red</a></li>` will filter all `.pin` divs with a list item of `Red`.

*EDIT:*

I'm looking more into the [:contains()](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector. Is this appropriate?

`.each` onclick look inside `.pin` if it contains `<.li>Red</li>` `.show` parent div?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may do what you are looking for...  it is only using jquery to iterate through the elements, so is doing the test for the "raw text" itself...

```
$(".pin a").click(function () {
    var lookingFor = $(this).text();
    $('.pin').hide();
    $('.pin li a').each(function (idx) {
        var $el = $(this);
        if ($el.text() === lookingFor) {
            $el.closest(".pin").show();
        }
    });
});
```

EDIT: based on the jsFiddle, this works without adding anchor tags (i agree with the poster that the anchor tags are unnecessary if you can just use the `cursor:pointer;` CSS.

```
$(".pin li").click(function() {
    var lookingFor = $(this).text();
    $('.pin').hide()
    $('.pin:contains(' + lookingFor + ')').show();
});
```

If you must have anchor tags, the following will do:

```
$(".pin a").click(function() {
    var lookingFor = $(this).text();
    $('.pin').hide()
    $('.pin:contains(' + lookingFor + ')').show();
});
```

not really sure which one would be faster...

(2nd edit: was using the wrong text for "lookingFor" variable...)

Comment: Thanks for the help @Leland I'm trying to apply this to my html. How do I wrap the li in anchor links first? http://jsfiddle.net/S5hKn/1/

Comment: @uriah see my edits above.  [here it is in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lelandrichardson/S5hKn/9/)

Comment: +1: nice, I didn't know about `contains`, you always learn something new

Comment: @LelandRichardson is there a way to `.append` the selected `.text`. Like "Showing: Yellow"

Comment: @LelandRichardson Worked it out! Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/gVpqx/

However, I would really suggest using classes, is way more reliable.
I dropped inserting the `a`, as it serves no purpose, just use a `cursor: pointer` stile on the `li` and you're good.

```
$(document).ready(function()
             {
             $("li").each(function(x){
                 $(this).click(function()
                     {
                     var tagval = $(this).html();
                     filterDivs(tagval);
                     });       
                 });

             $("#showall").click(function(){$(".pin").show();});             
             });


function filterDivs(tag)
         {
         $(".pin").each(function(x)
                   {
                   var ch = $(this).children("ul").children();
                   var tagfound = false;
                       console.log(ch.length);
                   for (c=0; c<ch.length; c++)
                       {
                       if ($(ch[c]).html() == tag)
                           {
                           tagfound = true;
                           break;
                           }
                       }
                   if (tagfound)
                       $(this).show();
                   else
                       $(this).hide();                               
                   });
         }
```

Comment: Wow @nico that's a lot of work. Thats outside of my knowledge. Leland's answer is much easier for me to follow and learn. Thanks heaps

Comment: this suited my application very well.